# Unable to create GitLab Webhooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab

When trying to add a Web Hook to my project in GitLab, it get a 500 error after submitting the form to create a Web Hook.

In gitlab.error.log file I have the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"test", :controller=>"projects/hooks", :project_id=>#<Project id: 28, name: "Sandbox", path: "sandbox", description: "Project for playing with Gitlab", created_at: "2014-01-16 19:47:00", updated_at: "2014-01-16 19:47:00", creator_id: 1, issues_enabled: true, wall_enabled: false, merge_requests_enabled: true, wiki_enabled: true, namespace_id: 1, issues_tracker: "gitlab", issues_tracker_id: nil, snippets_enabled: false, last_activity_at: "2014-01-22 15:48:34", imported: false, import_url: "", visibility_level: 10, archived: false>, :id=>#<ProjectHook id: nil, url: "", project_id: 28, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, type: "ProjectHook", service_id: nil, push_events: true, issues_events: false, merge_requests_events: false>, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
    52:       - @hooks.each do |hook|
    53:         %li
    54:           .pull-right
    55:             = link_to 'Test Hook', test_project_hook_path(@project, hook), class: "btn btn-small grouped"
    56:             = link_to 'Remove', project_hook_path(@project, hook), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-remove btn-small grouped"
    57:           .clearfix
    58:             %span.monospace= hook.url
  app/views/projects/hooks/index.html.haml:55:in `block in _app_views_projects_hooks_index_html_haml__3155439581843495211_69974122950540'
  app/views/projects/hooks/index.html.haml:52:in `_app_views_projects_hooks_index_html_haml__3155439581843495211_69974122950540'
  app/controllers/projects/hooks_controller.rb:22:in `create'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:57:in `set_current_user_for_thread'
```

This appears to mean that the Web Hook was not created or something is wrong with my GitLab setup that the id isn't being returned.  I am at a loss for how to debug this error further.

Comment: maybe this is your case https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6108 `The nil error happens because it tries to retrieve last and first commit from the repo, which do not exist`

Comment: @gotva That isn't my case.  The repo is not empty and there are no hooks to test.  The problem comes in the submission of the form to create a new one.

Comment: I suppose you use the last version 6-5-stable. It seems I understand what is going on [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/51f06bad0b3292226269ada45d6e6994182b6b7b/app/controllers/projects/hooks_controller.rb#L16): you build a new hook, it is not valid (BUT t already in memory and this hook without id appear in `@hooks = @project.hooks`), action renders `index` where app tries to build route to project_hook_path. But it raises an error because your last hook without id

Comment: I can't check but it looks like [this changes](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/d89527839ea0dd1734dacb71c3ed2a97f1ff74d7#diff-70498c6ab0e1c1ce1bc52739b88cf26cL21) break code. You can return code `@hooks = @project.hooks.all`, restart your gitlab and if it will work on your machine - post an issue to the official gitlab repo.

Comment: @gotva Undoing that change and restarting gitlab does not fix the problem.  I am not familiar with Ruby, just restarting the service should implement the changes, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion it looks like a bug in the Gitlab core. I can suggest you to do:

1. find out why your hook is invalid. for this you should change `@hook.save` on `@hook.save!` in [controller](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/51f06bad0b3292226269ada45d6e6994182b6b7b/app/controllers/projects/hooks_controller.rb#L16) (it will raise an exception if hook is invalid and you will see errors in the logs) 
   Maybe it is enough: you will see an error and will fix a reason(s) of the errors
2. you need to patch your local APP to continue to work. There are a lot of ways. I suggest you the simplest way - do not render that part of view if hook is not persisted (in DB)
   https://gist.github.com/gotva/8573700 - line 7. Be careful with indentations it is `haml`!
3. Please post an issue (bug) to the official repo. Gitlab is awesome project - let's help them to be a little bit better :)

PS (about restarting the APP) yes you are right it is enough to restart service

PPS do not forget to undo local changes when new version of Gitlab will be released

Comment: Thanks, changing to `@hook.save!` provided me with the information that I required.  The url was not valid due to a missing "http://"

Comment: please post a bug to Gitlab. It is normal that users do not exactly that developers expect - it is not good to see ErrorPage for users. Good luck